# Creating a Image Slideshow for each of a variable Number of img Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a slideshow for each element of a search result.

imagine the results will be like this:

```js
var speed = 1200;
var image = 0;
var slideimages = [
  ["http://www.digicpictures.com/images/upload/Thumbnails/about_digic_logo_neg_200x200.jpg"],
  ["http://flash.sonypictures.com/shared/global/images/sonypictures_share_200x200.jpg"],
  ["https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAATdAAAAJGZiYmMzZTAzLWM4MmUtNGIzYS1hZjNkLTY5YjFjMWRkOTViMA.png"]
];

$("div").mouseover(function() {
  var element = this.getElementsByTagName("img");

  clearTimeout(arguments.callee.to);
  image = ++image % slideimages.length;
  element[0].src = slideimages[image];
  //document.getElementById('test').src = slideimages[image];
  arguments.callee.to = setTimeout(arguments.callee, speed);

});

$("div").mouseout(function() {
  clearTimeout(arguments.callee.to);
});
```

```html
<div class="keyframe-img">
  <a class="videolink" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.digicpictures.com/images/upload/Thumbnails/about_digic_logo_neg_200x200.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="keyframe-img">
  <a class="videolink" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.digicpictures.com/images/upload/Thumbnails/about_digic_logo_neg_200x200.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

I wanted to add on each result a mouseover function to start the slideshow.
It basically replaces the current Image with another one from an Array.
But instead of using IDs to find the Image Tag (there are no IDs at all), i get them by using this.getElementsByTagName("img")
Of course now the Image changes one time and then the script stucks, because this is no longer the same element and there is no getElementsbyTagName function.
Of course. if i would use IDs, it would work perfectly.

Is there a way to get this work without using IDs?

Here ist a fiddle link btw: http://jsfiddle.net/ou0qqzfr/

My next step would be to use a different array for each div element. so if you have some ideas to do this, that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by making my element variable global and leave it empty. If i go by mouseover, the function checks only one time, if the variable is empty and initializes it as the img tag. the other times it just ignores the initialization.
if i leave with mouseout element will be empty again.
Not sure, if there are better solutions, but this will work for now.

```
var element = "";
var speed = 1200;
var image = 0;
var slideimages = [
  ["http://www.digicpictures.com/images/upload/Thumbnails/about_digic_logo_neg_200x200.jpg"],
  ["http://flash.sonypictures.com/shared/global/images/sonypictures_share_200x200.jpg"],
  ["https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAATdAAAAJGZiYmMzZTAzLWM4MmUtNGIzYS1hZjNkLTY5YjFjMWRkOTViMA.png"]
];

$("div").mouseover(function() {
  if (element == "")
    element = this.getElementsByTagName("img");

  clearTimeout(arguments.callee.to);
  image = ++image % slideimages.length;
  element[0].src = slideimages[image];
  arguments.callee.to = setTimeout(arguments.callee, speed);

});

$("div").mouseout(function() {
  clearTimeout(arguments.callee.to);
  element = "";
});
```